# Wordpress with user login and file manager support

Tags: file-manager

This may be a RTFM kind of thing, so I'll apologize up front. I've been asked by a friend I used to freelance for if there's a solution in Wordpress where users an login, then they can upload their own files in a "my docs" kind of thing.

I've never used WP, so before I dig into their info I thought I'd see if anyone here can confirm or maybe point me to a resource. It's one of those "I'll look up at lunch and get back to you" things, which is why I'm bugging you all before reading the docs.

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with the plugin repository. 9 times out of 10...

Answer (score 1):

I've created a file manager for client using the "list yo files" plugin.  You can find it in the repository, it's actively maintained and easy to use

Comment: Link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-yo-files/

Answer (score 0):

It's a $15 premium plugin from Code Canyon, but I believe it does exactly what you need.

http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-file-centre/112012